# enter url and input user details in a signin page, using keywords in the Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I want to run a script that will test a web application and then give me the number of tests that have passed and those that failed.

problem: I can't find a suitable Keyword to use that will visit the url to the login page in order to enter user details to sign in .

When I run the script, browser opens for a few seconds,and then it disappears.

Anyone, please help.

this is my code:

```
#LoginPage.robot
${BASE_URL}    =    # the url is here
# Input Data
&{User1}  Email=superman@gmail.com  Passw=0087564
&{User2}  Email=spiderman@gmail.com  Passw=667890
&{User3}  Email=betman@gmail.com  Passw=6554323
&{User4}  Email=pokimon@gmail.com  Passw=897655
&{User5}  Email=tom@gmail.com  Passw=12345678987



# LoginTestPage.robot
*** Test Cases ***
Verify user Signin
[Template]  LoginPage.Launch Sign in
${User1}
${User2}
${User3}
${User4}
${User5}
```

This is the outcome I get on Comand prompt:

```
Verify user Signin                                                    | FAIL |
Keyword 'LoginPage.Launch Signin' expected 0 arguments, got 1.
```

Comment: That error seems pretty self-explanatory. Apparently, `Launch Signin` doesn't require any parameters but you're sending it one. You need to either not send it any arguments, or change it so that it accepts an argument.

Comment: Thanks! I corrected it.